# 2017 store lists for avoiding chametz she'avar alav hapesach

Tags: kashrut-kosher, product-recommendation, chametz-leaven, selling-mechirat-chametz, hametz-sheavar-alav-pesah

Are there any lists available online of stores/store chains that are/not of concern with regard to *chametz she'avar alav hapesach* for 2017 - particularly for the New York metropolitan area?

Answer (score 5):

[Here is a list](https://images.shulcloud.com/731/uploads/AFTER-PESACH-STORES-MAIN-FLYER-2017.pdf) from [Cong. Ohab Zedek](https://www.ozny.org/home) in the Upper West Side.

Answer (score 1):

this is an email from the local koshrus organization in Philadelphia keystone-k:

Updated 4/20/2017 based on the latest information shared by the major kashrus agencies.

We have received queries about Target.  As of 4/18/2017 the status of Target has been changed to problematic.

Stores from which Chometz may be purchased after Pesach (Updates and Additions 4/20/2017):

Please read the following carefully to make sure that you don't miss anything.

Wine and liquor stores in Pennsylvania are owned by the state.  Therefore, "chometz" drinks which have no Kashrus or other concerns may be purchased at Pennsylvania State Stores immediately after Pesach.

Chometz may be purchased at any Keystone-K establishment.

Supermarkets and national chains are not considered Keystone-K establishments, but follow the following guidelines:

Chometz may be purchased after Pesach at KFM (Kosher Foods and More), ShopRite Roosevelt Blvd. and the following national chains :  Restaurant Depot, A & L (supplier),  Aldi, Save a Lot, CVS, Rite-Aid, Trader Joes, Walgreens, Walmart, K-Mart, Petco, Petsmart, and BJs, Costcos, Dollar Tree and Whole Foods, Food Lion, Mars, Royal Farms, Sam's Discount Warehouse, Shopper's Food Warehouse, Wegman's Winn-Dixie.

In addition to this the following stores in the (entire) Philadelphia area are OK: All Giants of the Ahold Group,  Wawa, and ShopRite Roosevelt Blvd.

Acmes now have significant Jewish ownership.  The OU took care of selling the "chometz" for all Acme Markets.

The Chometz at Shoprites and Fresh Grocers is taken care of by Wakefern.   Some people rely on this sale, while some are stringent.  You should ask your rabbi for guidance regarding those stores.

Quick turnover items may be purchased at any major store two weeks after Pesach.  Slower turnover items may be purchased four weeks after Pesach.

Food items which may contain an insignificant amount of Chometz may be purchased at any store after Pesach.